# how do I add a final variable to class diagram

Tags: class, uml, final, class-diagram

I am designing a class diagram for scrabble game. In one of the classes, I have final variable declared. Can anybody tell me, how can I indicate a variable as final in the UML class diagram?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Constant (i.e. final) fields are indicated via naming convention:
>   constants should be in ALL_CAPS

[Source](http://cs.nmu.edu/~mkowalcz/cs120f08/uml/UMLdiagram.html)

Comment: Whilst the naming convention would be a sufficient way of representing a constant, OP also has the opportunity to add a custom stereotype to constant attributes, e.g. «constant» or «final». This will be particularly useful is OP is trying to perform automated analysis on his model, for example using OCL.

Comment: [source](http://cs.nmu.edu/~mkowalcz/cs120f08/uml/UMLdiagram.html) dead :(

Comment: The source can be found on the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161217072701/http://euclid.nmu.edu/~mkowalcz/cs120f08/uml/UMLdiagram.html) in its state from 2016.  However, this is not a valid reference.  The answer of [Carsten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16253663/3723423) with a quote from the UML specs is much more accurate.

Answer (score 21):

There are different notions of final that are all represented in different ways:

- **final definition**, i.e. it cannot be overridden in sub-classes - this corresponds to the *isLeaf* property of the attribute:

  > The *isLeaf* property, when true for a particular RedefinableElement, specifies that it shall have no redefinitions. 
  > - *UML 2.5 specifications, page 99*

  There is no official notation anymore for attributes with *isLeaf=true*; adding `{leaf}` was the former official notation (UML 1.x) and it is still common.
- **final value**, i.e. its value cannot be changed - this corresponds to the *isReadOnly* property of the attribute:

  > If a StructuralFeature is marked with *isReadOnly* true, then it may not be updated once it has been assigned an initial value. Conversely, when *isReadOnly* is false (the default), the value may be modified. 
  > - *UML 2.5 specifications, page 106*

  Notation for read-only attributes consists of appending `{readOnly}` to the attribute string.
- **constant** usually refers to a non-changeable attribute of the class itself instead of an instance (**static final** attribute). In UML it would have both properties mentioned above and additionally be static, which corresponds to the *isStatic* property:

  > The *isStatic* property specifies whether the characteristic relates to the Classifier’s instances considered individually (*isStatic*=false), or to the Classifier itself (*isStatic*=true). 
  > - *UML 2.5 specifications, page 105*

  Static attributes are indicated by underlining the attribute definition. Constants, as already mentioned are usually UPPERCASE, but that's just a convention.

So, to sum it up, a constant attribute *FOO* of type *String* with value "x" would look like this and be underlined in addition (which isn't supported here):

```
+ FOO : String = "x" {readOnly,leaf}
```

Comment: I updated this excellent and comprehensive answer with references to the current UML specs.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable/attribute final is implementation detail. So you don't need to specify it in your CLASS Diagram but you can follow the convention as suggested by `eboix`.

UML specification doesn't say anything specifically about it; so you can follow convention of showing it in `ALL CAPS`.